# Android: is loading time of local HTML file into WebView affected by the storage place (internal storage/sdcard/external sd card)?

Tags: android, html, webview, loading, android-sdcard

I made a test activity that loads a local HTML file from external sdcard but I see it can be slow for my purpose. Could I put that file into internal memory to gain in speed? Is loading time affected by the place the HTML file is loaded from?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's device dependent, based on what kind of memory is used on that specific device. You can [use StrictMode](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/12/new-gingerbread-api-strictmode.html) to handle performance in a more general way.

That being said, I favor internal storage over external storage in general for speed purposes, especially for an HTML file that won't take up much space.

Comment: Could difference in loading time be huge?

Comment: Honestly, I would imagine your browser parsing takes the bulk majority of that time, but you should profile your application to be sure.